# Saving a number that increases on button click without server-side language

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an easy way to save a number that increases when the user clicks on a button without any `server-side` language? Here is my code:

```js
var num = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("coinBtn");
function coin() {
  num += 1;
  var numbers = document.getElementById("coinAm");
  //upgrade level for printing
  var upgradeLevel = document.getElementById("upgradeLevel");
  numbers.innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="coinAm" class="num"> 0 </h1>
   <br>
   <br>
<img onclick="coin()" id="coinBtn"  src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/Ihy0gO3MVhUqSY2jvS/giphy.gif?cid=19f5b51a1eda5f2b05af92f92452b8612b5e02a276803f0d&rid=giphy.gif">
```

Comment: to save it where?

Comment: I want to save it on the users computer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStrorage`, based on your need.

`localStorage.setItem("coinCount", num)` to save item.
`localStorage.getItem("coinCount")` to get item on page reload to get previous count.

**Note:** Live example won't work, due to security issue.

```js
var num = Number(localStorage.getItem("coinCount") || 0);
//var num = Number(sessionStrorage.getItem("coinCount") || 0);
var button = document.getElementById("coinBtn");
function coin() {
  num += 1;
  var numbers = document.getElementById("coinAm");
  //upgrade level for printing
  var upgradeLevel = document.getElementById("upgradeLevel");
  numbers.innerHTML = num;
  localStorage.setItem("coinCount", num)
  
  //sessionStrorage.setItem("coinCount", num)
}
```

```html
<h1 id="coinAm" class="num"> 0 </h1>
   <br>
   <br>
<img onclick="coin()" id="coinBtn"  src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/Ihy0gO3MVhUqSY2jvS/giphy.gif?cid=19f5b51a1eda5f2b05af92f92452b8612b5e02a276803f0d&rid=giphy.gif">
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do "save-like" functionality is to use `localStorage`.

So you could do something like this:

```
var num = 0;

var button = document.getElementById("coinBtn");

function coin() { 
    num += 1;
    var numbers = document.getElementById("coinAm");

        //upgrade level for printing
    var upgradeLevel = document.getElementById("upgradeLevel");

    numbers.innerHTML = num;
    localStorage.setItem('num', num); // save to localStorage 

}
```

Then to read it back from `localStorage`, you can do `localStorage.getItem('num');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage